# Interpreting a rootogram

Tags: generalized-linear-model, validation, zero-inflation

I recently needed to use a Zero-inflated Negative Binomial and Hurdle Negative Binomial models to model some data. When finding ways to assess the goodness of fit, I came across rootograms. But I am struggling with interpreting them, im pratical terms.

Considering the following example, from Christian Kleiber and Achim Zeileis (retrieved from ’Visualizing Count Data Regressions Using Rootograms’ published on August 10, 2016):

[image: example_rootogram]

How would one interpret this plot? I know what in the hanging plot, if the bar is over (and not touching) the $y=0$ line, the model is underpredicting that bin. If the bar is under (and not touching) the $y=0$, the model is overpredicting.
Underpredicting means that, for example, if there are four "2" values in the data (giving an example, based on the image), and the model is only predicting 3, this leads to said underprediction?

Still on the same topic, I am aware that the square root of the observed values is displayed. Why is that? So that in large numbers, the visualization of the plot is easier?
The square root is also applied to the fitted values, correct?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would one interpret this plot?

Your understanding seems correct: the red lines/dots show the expected (square root) frequencies that the model predicts, the grey bars show the (discrepancy from) the observed frequencies in the data. In the Poisson example these two quantities match quite well, although the model is slightly underpredicting the amount of 2's in the data - there's more observations with that outcome than the Poisson distribution specifies.

In the negative binomial case you can see that the model is underpredicting the lowest counts, *over*predicts between outcomes 3-5 (fewer observed in the data than expected from the distribution that was fit), and underpredicts again above that.

> The square root of the observed values is displayed. Why is that?

As the paper mentions, this is to allow discrepancies both in small and large frequencies to be more easily visualized:

> The square roots rather than the untransformed observations are employed
> to approximately adjust for scale differences across the $j$ values or intervals. Otherwise, deviations would only be visible for $j$’s with large observed/expected frequencies.

($j$'s being the possible outcomes on the x-axis here)

This square root scaling applies to the frequencies of both the observed and expected counts.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I saw very confused interpretations on rootograms :(